# Database INSERT statement

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

Do I need to create a new statement each time I execute a query?

This line doesn't work (I have already established connection with the database )

```
Statement.execute("INSERT INTO PS2 (uuid , team, kills , deaths , rank_lvl, rank_name, pts) "
                    + "VALUES"
                    + " (`" + name.toString() + "` , `none` , 0 , 0 , 1 , `Starter` , 0)");
```

I create the table with this code :

```
Statement.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PS2"
                + "(uuid VARCHAR(45),"
                + "team VARCHAR(20),"
                + "kills INTEGER,"
                + "deaths INTEGER,"
                + "rank_lvl INTEGER,"
                + "rank_name VARCHAR(25),"
                + "pts INTEGER)");
```

After executing the code , the database has been created . Afterwards after trying to insert row, the row is not created!

Comment: Are ` backticks correct as string quotes? Try `'`

Comment: There is no error , there is just no rows in the database , @AlexK. i am testing

Comment: What RDBMS do you use? Some of them are caching data and while you does'nt commit or flush there is no data written to disk.

Comment: What about the first question?

Comment: And never ever use a concat string for SQL. Use a `reusable` PreparedStatement.

Comment: Okay , btw there is a  **warning** "No index"

Comment: in java there is a Statement class having a static execute method ?

Comment: No , its a representation of my object

Comment: @Zarkopafilis Could you Post the JAVA Code to create the database object?

Comment: Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(host, username, password);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using backticks `` ` `` instead of quotes `'` to wrap your values. Backticks are only used to wrap column names.

```
Statement.execute("INSERT INTO PS2 (`uuid` , team, kills , deaths , rank_lvl, rank_name, pts) "
    + "VALUES"
    + " ('" + name.toString() + "' , 'none' , 0 , 0 , 1 , 'Starter' , 0)");
```

As mention by Caweren, you should be careful of [SQL reserved keywords](https://www.drupal.org/node/141051). `UUID` could be one of them (with an Oracle V9i database, for example), so you should wrap it with backticks.

Comment: I would manually try this request, to know it the problem come from the request, or from the code.

Comment: It worked manually :S , using this piece of code : INSERT INTO PS2(uuid , team , kills , deaths , rank_lvl , rank_name , pts) VALUES('460b9dd9-af9c-4942-a49d-28d365658e7a' , 'none' , 0 ,0 , 1 , 'Starter', 0)

Comment: There are no errors when executing the INSERT statement BUT the row is not created!

Comment: Then it come from somewhere else. What kind of database are you using ?

Comment: i use a mysql database . I connect via jdbc:mysql/blahblah/dbname . I used phpmyadmin in order to execute the statement

Comment: [Everything is correct](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e145db/1). Does any `INSERT` work via PHPMyAdmin (even on other tables) ?

Comment: Nice site youve got there. It worked via phpmyadmin. Its java - side issue? I just use a connection , create the statement , execute it , close the statement. No rows.What do i do?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56640/discussion-between-zessx-and-zarkopafilis).

Answer (score 0):

`uuid` is a reserved keyword for SQL, you should wrap it in quotes: `uuid`

Comment: The database got created without it being wrapped by quotes

Comment: Tables can be created using reserved words, but to use them in statements or clauses you have wrap them in quotes.